# Call Smart Contract Function in Python Script

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py, python

My situation is reverse to most. I am relatively experienced in coding in Solidity, but have absolutely no experience in using Python.

What I would ideally like to do is have a script that will, in predetermined time intervals, call a Smart Contract Function and give it the required input, then read and possibly store the output.

I need help figuring out the "calling the function" part. Please dont just point me to web3.py, I looked it over and while it seems very useful I dont know where to start and I dont have the time to take it from the top right now. If you could provide some help specifically on what I am asking for, please do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using [Brownie](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/brownie) that should help:

```py
import time
from brownie import Contract, network, web3


abi = {}          # contract ABI as a dict
address = "0x00"  # contract address as a string


network.connect('mainnet')
my_contract = Contract("MyContractName", address, abi=abi)

height = web3.eth.blockNumber

while True:
    result = my_contract.myCallableFn(arg1, arg2) # change to call the desired method
    if result == desired_result:
        # do whatever you need to do

    while web3.eth.blockNumber == height:
        time.sleep(1)
    height = web3.eth.blockNumber
```

You will have to modify some configuration settings to point at your own node, or [set an infura API key](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nonlocal-networks.html#defining-non-local-networks) in your environment variables.

The documentation on [accessing contract methods](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interaction.html#accessing-contract-methods) might also be useful if my example is unclear.

Hope this helps.